# Calculate the cumulative “bid” and “ask” ratio

Tags: dolphindb

Originally, I wrote the factor expression in Python. Now I want to use it in dolphinDB quickly and do parallel computing by the computing engine of dolphinDB. How to implementit with a minimal change?
Here is an example: to calculate the cumulative bid and ask ratio

```py
ask = df["av1"]
bid = df["bv1"]
p = df["mp"].iloc[0]
for i in range(2,11):    
     ask += np.exp(-10*(i-1)/p)*df["av"+str(i)]
     bid += np.exp(-10*(i-1)/p)*df["bv"+str(i)]
     vol_diff = 0.5*np.log(bid/ask)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used directly in the DolphinDB database:

```py
def factorVolDiff(t){
  w = exp(-10 * 0..9/t.mp[0])
  return select 0.5*log(rowSum([bv1,bv2,bv3,bv4,bv5,bv6,bv7,bv8,bv9,bv10]*w)/rowSum([av1,av2,av3,av4,av5,av6,av7,av8,av9,av10]*w)) as volDiff from t
 }
```